# Pop up keyboards with the supported language - Objective C

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I am a new to iPhone development, I'm asking for your help to find out whether it is possible to pop up keyboards with the supported language that I have added in `NSLocalizedString`.

I can show my `UIlabel` strings in the appropriate language, now I want keyboards in the same language.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you can't control the language of keyboard**.

Only user can change the language through the settings app or through the globe key present in the keyboard.

Comment: now i got it.. if user add manually the keyboard language he need , he can toggle keyboard language using the globe key present in the keyboard.. thank you man!